# Google app script regex phone

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script

Have such code:
https://github.com/dezostus/googleapp/blob/master/z_draft/email%20parce(test).gs

Problem with this regex it this part:

```
.match(/Phone:^((8|\+)[\- ]?)?(\(?\d{3}\)?[\- ]?)?[\d\- ]{7,10}$/);
.match(/Comment:\s*([\s\S]+)(?=Email|Phone)/);
```

Phone dont return anything.. true many things, but finally nothing works. Possible mask is:

```
12361234567
8029123456
+12361234567
+375 29 123 45 67
4(123)123-45-67
123-45-67
9261234567
```

Comment works well with:

```
Comment: ТestABC1234567 Ads
Phone: +313239084
or
Comment: ТestABC1234567 Ads
Email: asd@gmail.com
```

but when template like this:

```
Comment: ТestABC1234567 Ads
Phone: +313239084
Email: asd@gmail.com
```

it return:

```
ТestABC1234567 Ads
Phone: +313239084
```

Would be grateful for any variants how to solve this

Comment: Do you have `Phone:` before the numbers? If yes, then you surely do not need `^` in the phone regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd rather use

```
/Phone:\s*((?:[48+][- ]?)?(?:\(?\d{3}\)?[- ]?)?[\d -]{7,10})/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xL6wV2/1)

I added `4` as an alternative to what may be at the beginning (one of the numbers starts with `4`). So, I used `[48+]` (either `4` or `8` or `+`).

I removed unnecessary escape symbols, no need to escape the hyphen in the initial or final positions in the character class.

I removed the redudant capturing groups or turned into non-capturing, and set 1 capturing group you need that stores the actual number (it will be Group 1).

I also removed the anchors, they can be used only with the `/m` modifier since the input is multiline. However, there may be leading trailing spaces. If you really want to keep the `^` and `$`, try `/^\s*Phone:\s*((?:[48+][- ]?)?(?:\(?\d{3}\)?[- ]?)?[\d -]{7,10})\s*/m`.

Comment: Thanks!! Works well in all variants and also for regex101.com, now would test everything here))

Answer (score 2):

Since Wiktor has already tackled your first issue, here's a possible solution for your second issue:

```
/Comment:\s*([\s\S]+?)(?=(?:Phone|Email))/
```

However, if the words *Email* or *Phone* appear in your Comment, you will need to use the following instead, assuming that `Phone` and `Email` entries always start on newlines:

```
/Comment:\s*([\s\S]+?)(?=(?:\nPhone|\nEmail))/
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/gG0aG1/6)

```js
var strs = [
  'Comment: Comment Type 1 ТestABC1234567 Ads\n\
    Email: asd@gmail.com\n\
    Phone: +313239084',
  
  'Comment: Comment Type 2 ТestABC1234567 Ads\n\
    Phone: +313239084\n\
    Email: asd@gmail.com',
  
  'Comment: Comment Type 3 ТestABC1234567 Ads\n\
    Phone: +313239084', 
  
  'Comment: Comment Type 4 ТestABC1234567 Ads\n\
    Email: asd@gmail.com'
];

var re = /Comment:\s*([\s\S]+?)(?=(?:Phone|Email))/;

strs.forEach(function(str) {
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', str.match(re).slice(1) + '<br>');
});
```

Comment: Just wow, thank for fast and detail answer! Pitty, that cant choose two answer that help solve problem

Comment: @Twil: No problem, I will add up on timolawl rep.

Comment: @Twil: No worries. The fact that you're actively contributing with comments and accepting answers puts you miles ahead of most of the users on this site, and that's very good.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That's very kind of you! I will return the favor. Your answers have always been illuminating.